# How to create a rotation animation in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Looks like `QPropertyAnimation` has no 'rotation' animation

i tried using a `QVariantAnimation` but the animation looks weird: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGXNO.gif

**-EDIT-**

I have updated the code with commented suggestions

Compilable example:

```
// mainwindow.h
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindowClass; };
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass *ui;
};
```

```
// mainwindow.cpp
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "pusharrow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindowClass())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");
    PushArrow* label = new PushArrow(this);
    label->setStyleSheet("background-color: green;");
    label->setGeometry(100, 100, 32, 32);
    label->show();


    PushArrow_2* label_2 = new PushArrow_2(this);
    label_2->setStyleSheet("background-color: green;");
    label_2->setGeometry(200, 100, 32, 32);
    label_2->show();
}
```

```
// pusharrow.h

// arrow.png: https://i.imgur.com/PymLF1N.png

class PushArrow : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QVariantAnimation* animation;
    QPixmap pixmap;
    QPixmap transformedPixmap;
    bool down = false;

    PushArrow(QWidget* parent = 0) : QLabel(parent) 
    { 
        pixmap = QPixmap("C:/Users/arrow.png");
        setPixmap(pixmap);

        animation = new QVariantAnimation(this);
        animation->setDuration(500); // Using a higher value to see how the animation is being performed.

        connect(animation, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, [=](const QVariant &value)
        {
            qDebug() << value;
            QTransform t;
            t.rotate(value.toReal());
            transformedPixmap = pixmap.transformed(t, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
            setPixmap(transformedPixmap);
        });
    }



    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        down = !down;
        if (down)
        {
            animation->setStartValue(0.0f);
            animation->setEndValue(-180.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            animation->setStartValue(-180.0f);
            animation->setEndValue(0.0f);
        }

        animation->start();
        QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    }
};



class PushArrow_2 : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QPixmap pixmap;
    QPixmap transformedPixmap;

    bool down = false;
    QTimer* m_timer;
    qreal value = 0.0f;
    qreal startValue;
    qreal endValue;

    PushArrow_2(QWidget* parent = 0) : QLabel(parent) 
    { 
        pixmap = QPixmap("C:/Users/arrow.png");
        transformedPixmap = pixmap;

        m_timer = new QTimer(this);
        m_timer->setInterval(2);

        connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]
        {
            if (endValue < 0)
            {
                value -= 1.0f;

                if (abs(value) >= abs(endValue))
                {
                    m_timer->stop();
                    value = endValue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                value += 1.0f;

                if (value >= abs(endValue))
                {
                    m_timer->stop();
                    value = endValue;
                }
            }

            //qDebug() << value;
            QTransform t;
            t.rotate(value);
            transformedPixmap = pixmap.transformed(t, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
            repaint();
        });

    }



    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        down = !down;
        if (down)
        {
            startValue = 0.0f;
            endValue = -180.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            startValue = -180.0f;
            endValue = 0.0f;
        }

        m_timer->start();
        QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    }



    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override
    {
        //qDebug() << "rect: " << rect();
        //qDebug() << "transformedPixmap: " << transformedPixmap.rect();

        //QLabel::paintEvent(event);
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        painter.drawPixmap(rect(), transformedPixmap, transformedPixmap.rect());
    }
};
```

Using the paintEvent the animation is 'almost' correct, i dont understand why the pixmap is getting deformed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MqpH.gif

Comment: The "weird" is almost certainly because the center of rotation and rotation are done independently of position, then the position is calculated using the new image size.  The layout algorithm doesn't know it should be keeping the center of rotation in a consistent place.

Comment: @BenVoigt what do you suggest? editing the rotation in the paintevent and also adjust the xy position on the draw.pixmap?

Comment: Make the layout not depend on an auto-sized QLabel.  One possibility would be to put the QLabel inside some panel that has a fixed size.  Let that panel be right-justified (or whatever your layout calls for), and then set the QLabel to centered inside the panel.

Comment: Temporarily turning on a border would likely help you understand the problem intuitively.

Comment: @BenVoigt i tried using paint event the animation looks better, but i couldn't figure why the image is being painted 'deformed'

Comment: It's because it's being stretched from a varying size (determined by rotation) to a fixed size.  So the stretch ratio is changing, creating your "deformation"

Comment: @BenVoigt do you know how i could fix or improve it?

Comment: @Vitor added to my answer how I think you can avoid deformation.

Answer (score 0):

For "more smooth" there is second parameter of `transformed()` that is `Qt::FastTransformation` by default. Try:

```
transformedPixmap = pixmap.transformed(t, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

About "less weird" it is hard to tell. Can you get `QPainter` to `drawPixmap()` those transformed pixmaps anywhere in a way that does not look "weird" to you? If so then it is issue of how `QLabel` `paintEvent()` does it and you need to use something else or to override the behavior.

**Edit:**
If transformations change pixmap's width and height then do not stretch it, paint into centre. For example with something like that:

```
int x = rect().x() + (rect().width() - transformedPixmap.rect().width())/2;
int y = rect().y() + (rect().height() - transformedPixmap.rect().height())/2;
painter.drawPixmap(x, y, transformedPixmap);
```